# snowflake.com / views / sdk

Tags: sdk, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Thank you for your time.

I am new to snowflake, there are views (big SQL queries) created by our data team, I have a task to get data from that predefined 'view' aka query out of snowflake and into our project via the snowflake SDK / whatever api is available. I can see how we would make a query to snowflake and get data, but that would be to run a sql query defined in our code, not get the query which is defined in a view on snowflake... hope that make sense to you.

How do i query a view? Any help appreciated, is it as simple as:

```
  const result = connection.execute({
    sqlText: "SELECT * FROM x.y.z" 
  });
```

Comment: Querying a View is exactly the same as querying a Table

Comment: Thanks - if you want to add your comment as an answer i will mark solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying a View is exactly the same as querying a Table, so you can use the same syntax